# echoing mutiple variable + asterisk in bash

Tags: bash, variables, echo, asterisk

I am trying to echo / redirect to file two or three variables and asterisk;
However, as long as I am trying to include more than only one then my variables disappears.

Loading variables from file.
var:

```
CMD=/home/user1/command.sh
HOUR=17
MN=00
```

Here is a snippet of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. var
    if [ "${MN}" == "00" ];
    then
    MN=0
    fi

echo "${MN} ${HOUR} * * * user1 ${CMD}" >> ./test.log
```

the output look like the following which does not include all variables:

```
* * * root /home/user1/command.sh
```

It seems that for some reason while loading these variables from file; these cannot be reused.
As soon as I set them manually as part of the script itself, the output is as below and correct:

```
0 17 * * * root /home/user1/command.sh
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Many thanks,
AL.

Comment: Check if the `var` file has DOS line endings?

Comment: See item 1 on the [bash info wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) page.

Comment: Add full path to file var in your script.

Comment: ok, I got it. indeed - each line were having Dos line endings..

Answer (score 0):

Crontab execute that script not in  /home/user1/ folder.

So you need use /home/user1/var for variable include or do

```
cd /home/user1/
```

before include file with variables.